# MarshalByRefObject передаётся по ссылке или делает копию?

Tags: c#, appdomain

Есть 2 `AppDomain` с `LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost`. 
Есть общая сборка, скажем `Common.dll`, которая загружена в AppDomain1 и в AppDomain2.
В сборке `Common.dll` есть класс:

```
class MethodArgs:MarshalByRefObject  
{
    public string MethodName { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

При передаче экземпляра этого класса из AppDomain1 в AppDomain2 передача идёт по ссылке или всё же копируется, а потом делается ссылка?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, копия не создаётся (потому что это сделать в общем случае невозможно). Создаётся proxy-объект, который ведёт себя как оригинал, и все вызовы переправляет оригиналу.

Comment: Так как это класс, то он передается по ссылке. Параметры сериализуются, передаются через домен и десериализуются. В этом может быть критичная задержка.

Answer (score 10):

Несмотря на название класса `MarshalByRefObject`, передача происходит не совсем по ссылке. Упрощенная схема выглядит примерно так:

1. На вызывающей стороне создается два прокси - `System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy`, который по всем признакам является объектом оригинального типа - `MethodArgs`, и `RealProxy`, который умеет перебрасывать вызов в другой домен.
2. Рантайм перехватывает все обращения к методам и свойствам прокси, и проверяет, находится ли их реальный объект для этого `__TransparentProxy` в другом домене. Если объект в том же домене - то происходит простой вызов метода.
3. Иначе - рантайм собирает все параметры, оборачивает их в IMessage, и отдает его в метод `RealProxy.Invoke(...)`.
4. `RealProxy` (точнее, его реализация для кросс-доменных вызовов) перебрасывает вызов в другой домен, десериализует параметры и вызывает метод у реального объекта.

`__TransparentProxy` - системный класс, и его поведение нельзя поменять.

Поведение `RealProxy`, напротив, можно полностью кастомизировать, что позволяет использовать его, например, трассировки/подмены результатов вызовов - создания моков. Или для балансировки нагрузки - перенаправления вызовов от одного `__TransparentProxy` к нескольким реальным объектам.

Аттрибут `LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost` не оказывает никакого влияния на поведение `MarshalByRefObject`.

Более подробно о механизме proxy в ремоутинге:

- [Microsoft .NET Remoting: A Technical Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973857%28v=msdn.10%29#hawkremoting_topic3)
- [Transparent Proxy](https://web.archive.org/web/20160228180200/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/07/14/51495.aspx)